# What HTTP Status code makes in case a version of the resource asked is not available on server

Tags: rest, http

We have a REST endpoint which returns a specific version of the resource which was requested. 
The version is a part of the URL path parameter e.g.
 '/resource/version/{versionNumber}'

In case the requested version of the resource is not available what return code is appropriate? (404 seems appropriate)

Also, does it change if the resource itself is not available (or due to the request we should consider resource with a particular version as the single resource)

e.g.

Available resources:

resourceA:
        version: v1.0

1. /resourceA/vesrion/v2.0 what response
2. /resouceB/version/v1.0 what response

Comment: Is this part of an existing framework of client/server API access or are you able to invent whatever you want here? 404 is generally fine when something isn't there. 302 (redirect) may be useful if appropriate in some cases. But you say "not available"-- are you implying that this is a temporary or transient condition? When it's the resource itself (and not just one version of it) that is invalid do you wish to make that distinction to the client? I do hear what you're asking but you're omitting a bunch of context about the surrounding system that might clarify how to best approach this.

Comment: It's a new API. the resource is retrieved from DB and thus its availability once added is kind of permanent (unless DB not available or resource not even created). As a general practice, it good to consider a resource and it's version requested as one resource or independent? As in the case of former one response should suffice but in case of the latter different responses(or response messages) might be needed.

Comment: I think this is less about the status codes as such, and more about what your API clients already know and need to know, and what your service is willing to or needs to tell them. I don't think there is a general practice here-- it depends a lot on your what your service and API is doing and what clients you are expecting to connect to it! For the clients you imagine existing, does one response seem like it suffices for both cases? Or will it be important for the client to know more?

Comment: Yes, I agree that part of it depends on the specific use of the API. But as mentioned in the answer by @VoiceOfUnreason I think general practices should not be totally governed by the current use case or the clients, as these may change but the basic should be mostly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember: the client isn't supposed to be able to tell that your API isn't just some web site (uniform interface is one of the REST constraints, after all).

If the client sends a request, and you don't have a current representation that matches the target URI, then 404 is appropriate.  The message *body* might include more specific hints "Did you mean [alternative-spelling]?", but the semantics of response code are part of the common understanding of HTTP.